# NServicebus monitoring with ServiceInsight

Tags: nservicebus

I tried ServiceInsight/ServicePulse to monitor our NServibuce infrastructure.

However, the ServiceControl service can monitor only one error queue.

For multiple environments(dev/int/acc/prod), what is the best practice?
I guess the best is to install one ServiceControl service by environment?

We have also handlers on multiple servers. In order to monitor everything with one ServiceControl, all handlers must point to the same error queue. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For multiple environments(dev/int/acc/prod), what is the best practice?
>   I guess the best is to install one ServiceControl service by environment?

Yes that is the best practice.

> We have also handlers on multiple servers. In order to monitor everything with one ServiceControl, all handlers must point to the same error queue. Correct?

Yes you should centralise the error and audit queues per environment.

Do these answers make sense?

Comment: That's what I thought. I needed a confirmation. Thanks!